# how do i stop the scene from being blank in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

when i run all i get is a black scene none of my images appear i have tried changing key names but it doesn't seem to work
this is what it currently looks like when i run it. you can get the code from the link below for editing and testing. i know it calls the js file and creates a canvas but it then does not load my assets

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yKBofuaQlvGnO0hmXv6Fa1SRgP6Q4-HX?usp=sharing